# Sql query Inner join with specific data in string

Tags: mysql, join

Please find my below 2 table's where i want to execute inner join query with the specific condition.

Table Name:- table1

[image]

Table Name:- table2

[image]

In **table2 column Sr** after **#** there are some number's which is similar to **table1 column Sr** number's.I want to do inner join as per that particular number.

Please guide me with which condition I will managed to do inner joint with described situation.

Comment: use `substring_index()` to part out the values to the right of # and then use that as your join criteria.  Don't expect it to be fast since this will not be able to use indexes. [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: Would it be a better idea so extract these numbers into an other column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Demo from RexTester.com](http://rextester.com/GBQU96396)

Assumption:  table2.Name is always formatted with exactly 1 `#` hastag/pound sign/number sign followed by the matching digits in table 1.

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.value
FROM table2 T2
INNER JOIN table1 T1
 on T1.SR = substring_index(T2.Name,'#',-1);
```

FROM [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)
```

Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
'www.mysql'
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -2);
'mysql.com'
```

Disclaimer: Given we are using string manipulation on a join, no index will be able to be used.